# Python WooCommerce API JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Tags: python, json, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

**Set-up**

I'm using a [Python wrapper](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-python) and the [WooCommerce REST API](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#introduction) to connect to my webshop.

The connection is succesfully made using,

```
from woocommerce import API

wcapi = API(
    url="http://example.com",
    consumer_key="ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    consumer_secret="cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    wp_api=True,
    version="wc/v1"
)
```

To obtain product info, I use,

```
products = wcapi.get("products")
```

To read out the products, I use

```
products.text
```

which correctly gives me the products. See https://pastebin.com/E3r2R1GF.

---

**Problem**

The `.text` produces a messy layout. I rather have it in a library. So, I use,

```
products.json()
```

but this gives the following error,

```
  File "<ipython-input-31-c9e41d3bee87>", line 1, in <module>
    products.json()

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 518, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 370, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s)

  File "/Applications/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 400, in raw_decode
    return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end())

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what "products.text" looks like ?

Comment: No you don't. Because you're so polite I've added it.

Comment: Ok now I can politely answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Well quite obviously, assuming that `.json()` can take whatever piece of broken markup and automagically turns it into something json-compliant is plain wrong ;)

Oh and yes - the *source* of the problem is that - as often with php stuff - what was probably supposed to be a proper json response is polluted by php:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/home/pedicure/public_html/pedicuremotorkopen.be/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-parcelpro_1-2-8/admin/data/parcelpro-shipping-settings-services.php</b> on line <b>88</b><br />
[{"id":25348,"name":"Star Design Spa & Massage","slug":"star-design-spa-massage","permalink":"https:\/\/en.pedicuremotorkopen.be\/product\/star-design-spa-massage\/","date_created":"2018-01-23T11:46:28","date_modified":"2018-02-
```

etc...

EDIT:

> How can I make sure the json doesn't consider the **Warning**?

As I mentionned, the source problem is with PHP itself. If you have admin access to this site, you can change the php settings to prevent it from displaying spurious warning messages (which I would recommand if the site is actually on production).

For a more general answer, I'd say that a site returning anything else than well formed json for what is supposed to be "application/json" content-type is broken and that it's not your responsability (as the person writing client code) to "fix" it - just warn the site's admin about the problem and wait until he fixes it (cf above).

Now You *could* of course try to be "tolerant" and fix the response content by yourself but you'll have to do so manually and it will be brittle at best since you have no failsafe way to tell what's part of the json and what's not (such php pollution can happen just anywhere in the response content).

Comment: I'm just following the REST API's manual, where they advise me to do this; https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-products. Also, connecting exactly the same way to my other stores doesn't give this error, hence my question. I see you were being polite again, but you covered it up with a smiley. Thank you for pointing out the error. How can I make sure the json doesn't consider the `<b>Warning</b>`? Edit the `text` string and then `json()` it?

Comment: cf my edited answer. TL;DR : tell the site admin to fix his site, as the client part developper it's not your responsability to deal with broken json.